# How to convert data from an excel spreadsheet to a suitable representation for training a scikit-learn model

Tags: python, classification, svm, scikit-learn

I have the input data from an excel file, that I have processed in the manner below using nltk:

```
rb = open_workbook('subjectcat.xlsx')#C:/Users/5460/Desktop/
wb = copy(rb) #making a copy
sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)

data = ()

for row_index in range(1,500): #train using 500
    temp,add = (),()
    subject,cat = 0,0 #trial
    for col_index in range(1,3):        
        if col_index==1:
            #print col_index
            subject = sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value
            #print subject
            #print cellname(row_index,col_index)
            subject = "'" + subject
            #temp +=(subject,)
            #print temp
        elif col_index==2:
            #print col_index
            cat = sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value
            #print cat
            #print cellname(row_index,col_index)
            cat = "'" + cat + "'"
            add = add + (subject,cat)
            #print (add)
        data = data + (add,)

print 'done'
training_data = list(data)
training_data = training_data[1:][::2] #removing the even items
```

I have to now proceed to use scikit-learn to train the classifier. I have read through many tutorials for svm online, but they all seem to use different ways of creating datasets for use. I would be grateful if anyone can give me tips on how to proceed, as I am stuck for now. I am training classifier to classify emails into categories. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very bad question title. In particular "using data svm in sklearn" does not mean anything. A better title would be: how to convert data from an excel spreadsheet to a suitable representation for training a scikit-learn model.

Comment: Oh thanks. I will change it accordingly. I was trying to give a general idea of the contents involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your input data as a 2D numpy array: one row per sample / instance / observation. The column of the array should store the numerical descriptors (features) for the samples.

You need to store output / target classes as another numpy array of integers. Each target class should be assigned a integer (e.g. 0 for "ham" and 1 for "spam").

The output / target classes array should have as many entries as there are rows in your input data (one label per sample).

Read the documentation of numpy if you don't know how transform Python list to numpy arrays. You can start here:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html

To get a good predictive accuracy for SVM you also need to make sure that your features are meaningful (for instance don't use a string or integer representations to encode categorical input feature, but use a one-hot-encoding feature expansion) and standardize your data to center and scale to unit variance. In particular have a look at:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html

**Edit**: I had not seen you last statement: if your input data is raw email text, you have to extract features (numerical descriptors that statistically summarize the email content). You will need text feature extraction in that case:

- http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your time. So, if I am not wrong, it should be an array, one row per document, and each column will be per token. Is that right? I am using Tfidf-CoundVectorizer.

Comment: Also, for basic input into the svm, I need 2 arrays. One is a 2D array for the input data(email subjects, in my case) and one is a 1D array for categories in numerical form. Did I understand it right? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: No because the 2D array need to be numerical descriptors. So you need to extract bag of words features from your text content.